# Could not start zookeeper for kafka on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

from `C:\Program Files\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0` frolder I try to execute following command:

```
bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties
```

and it reponds with following message:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried to use several another variants but I still see errors:

```
C:\Program Files\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0>bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat
USAGE: bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat zookeeper.properties
```

---

```
C:\Program Files\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0>bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat C:\Program Files\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0\config\zookeeper.properties
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

---

```
C:\Program Files\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0>bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat 'C:\Program Files\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0\config\zookeeper.properties'
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: Use Linux. This is my advise with zero unpacking.

Answer (score 0):

your command should be

```
bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties
```